# Get place id address for bunch of items

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I have a json object with some place id. Now I am trying to get the respective address for each item.

This is what I am trying:

```
<div id="places" class="places"></div>
<script>
  function initialize() {
    json_data = jQuery.parseJSON(...);

    for (i = 0; i < json_data.length; i++) {
      console.log(json_data[i].id);
      console.log(json_data[i].key);

      var request = {
        placeId: json_data[i].key
      };

      service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(document.getElementById("places"));
      service.getDetails(request, callback);

      function callback(place, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
          $(".places").append("<p>" + request.placeId + " - " + place.formatted_address + "</p>");
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

However the output is not what I am expecting. The console.log is ok, but the append only shows some data from the API. [DEMO](https://jsbin.com/ruyukojega/1/edit?html,output)

It seems like the api takes some time to process. Not sure how to handle that.

Comment: so many global variables, use `var`, `const`, or `let`

Comment: @epascarello SO is funny nowadays. Question with no code Downvote. Question with code Downvote. Question with demo Downvote. Question with data to reproduce the exact problem Downvote. That's it.

Comment: I did not down vote and I was writing an answer, so maybe I should stop.

Comment: @epascarello I am not saying you are the downvoter, but it's frustrating.

Comment: One issue is the fact you are redefining request on every iteration and use it in the callback.... Second issue is what I mentioned that everything you declare is global

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to execute bunch of place details requests on the client side JavaScript code. The most important thing you should be aware of is the existence of client side rate quota. It was mentioned in the previous version of documentation, however, I cannot find it in the new Google Maps Platform documentation. Not sure if Google will remove this limit after July 16, 2018 after official launch of new pricing model.

In old documentation it was mentioned this way:

> Service requests are rate-limited per user session, regardless of how many users share the same project. When you first load the service API, you are allocated an initial quota of requests. Once you use this quota, the API enforces rate limits on additional requests on a per-second basis. If too many requests are made within a certain time period, the API returns an OVER_QUERY_LIMIT response code. The per-session rate limit prevents the use of client-side services for batch requests. For batch requests, use the Maps API web services.

Typically per-session quota allowed a bucket of 10 requests, once bucket is empty you could execute only 1 request per second. So you have to check the state of the response and in case of OVER_QUERY_LIMIT repeat request after 1 second delay.

I modified your code in order to solve your issue

```js
function initialize() {
    var json_data = jQuery.parseJSON('[ { "id": 146, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 145, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 144, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 143, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 142, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 141, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 140, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 139, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 138, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 137, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 136, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 135, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 134, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 133, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 132, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 131, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 130, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 129, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 128, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 127, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 126, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 125, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 124, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 123, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 122, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 121, "key": "ChIJ2QhxhMHOHg0RF8zBGoV9sVQ" }, { "id": 120, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 119, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 118, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 117, "key": "ChIJwVPhxKtlJA0RvBSxQFbZSKY" }, { "id": 116, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 115, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 114, "key": "ChIJwVPhxKtlJA0RvBSxQFbZSKY" }, { "id": 113, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 112, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 111, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 110, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 109, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 108, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 107, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 106, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 105, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 104, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 103, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 102, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 101, "key": "ChIJEYNl2y3JHg0R9zyZw3xCJ6A" }, { "id": 100, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 99, "key": "ChIJ9QQaFsHOHg0ROav_i9VD3V4" }, { "id": 98, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 97, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 96, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 95, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 94, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 93, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 92, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 91, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 90, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 89, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 88, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 87, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 86, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 85, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 84, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 83, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 82, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 81, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 80, "key": "ChIJSfWKOnvMHg0RqLLi-22LWnI" }, { "id": 79, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 77, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 76, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 75, "key": "ChIJwVPhxKtlJA0RvBSxQFbZSKY" }, { "id": 74, "key": "ChIJ4zGTOfhmJA0RfmcqcLKlVKk" }, { "id": 73, "key": "ChIJQRdO0HrMHg0RThqjF9M9-4w" }, { "id": 72, "key": "ChIJbdGsShT5Ig0RuaZCe0dkRWM" }, { "id": 71, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 70, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 69, "key": "ChIJr367qitvJA0Rvy5Oh88YCUE" }, { "id": 68, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 67, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 66, "key": "ChIJwVPhxKtlJA0RvBSxQFbZSKY" }, { "id": 65, "key": "ChIJK8leGat-GA0R6uUjP8gMizY" }, { "id": 64, "key": "ChIJwVPhxKtlJA0RvBSxQFbZSKY" }, { "id": 63, "key": "ChIJwVPhxKtlJA0RvBSxQFbZSKY" }, { "id": 62, "key": "ChIJzVzD6z42Iw0RmkTnIYjAv_Y" }, { "id": 61, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 60, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 59, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 58, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 57, "key": "ChIJwVPhxKtlJA0RvBSxQFbZSKY" }, { "id": 56, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 55, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 54, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 53, "key": "ChIJwVPhxKtlJA0RvBSxQFbZSKY" }, { "id": 52, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 51, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 50, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 49, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 48, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 47, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 46, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 45, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 44, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 43, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 42, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 41, "key": "ChIJwVPhxKtlJA0RvBSxQFbZSKY" }, { "id": 40, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 39, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 38, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 37, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 36, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 35, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 34, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 33, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 32, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 31, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 30, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 29, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 28, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 27, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 26, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 25, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 24, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 23, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 22, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 21, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 20, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 19, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 18, "key": "ChIJVT4alwcuGQ0RoHvco1jDCQ0" }, { "id": 17, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 16, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 15, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 14, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 13, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 12, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 11, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 10, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 9, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 8, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 7, "key": "ChIJyxnnULr4Gg0R9zGpUZLEL1M" }, { "id": 6, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 5, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 4, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 3, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" }, { "id": 2, "key": "ChIJS2ITKK8zGQ0R4ECQ5L3rAAU" }, { "id": 1, "key": "ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ" } ]');
            
            var delayFactor = 0;
            var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(document.getElementById("places"));

            function m_get_places (request) {
                service.getDetails(request, function(place, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                        $(".places").append("<p>" + request.placeId + " - " + place.formatted_address + "</p>");
                    } else if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT) {
                        delayFactor++;
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            m_get_places(request);
                        }, delayFactor * 1000);
                    } else {
                        console.log(status);
                    }
                });
            } 
         
            for (i = 0; i < json_data.length; i++) { 
                console.log( json_data[i].id );
                console.log( json_data[i].key );
                
                var request = {
                    placeId: json_data[i].key
                };
            
                m_get_places(request);
            }       
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDztlrk_3CnzGHo7CFvLFqE_2bUKEq1JEU&libraries=places&callback=initialize"></script>
<div id="places" class="places"></div>
```

You can find this example on jsfiddle as well: https://jsfiddle.net/xomena/kvq07xyr/

I hope this helps!

Comment: It makes sense. Thank you